# IOwinContext.Get<DbContext>() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to add authentication to add authentication to an existing MVC 5 application I started from an empty project. I started a new WebAPI project with individual user accounts so I could see how it was configured.  I copied over the code having to do with authentication and refactored the namespaces and class names. In the code below, the first line `var identityContext = context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()` returns null and causes the second line `var userStore = new UserStore<AdminAppUser>(identityContext)`  to throw an error due to a null parameter.

I probably didn't include enough code, as I am very new to MVC Authentication and have a poor understanding of how all the pieces fit together.  if I need to include more code please let me know which pieces would be useful. Thank you!

```
public static AdminAppUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<AdminAppUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {

        var identityContext = context.Get<IdentityDbContext>();
        var userStore = new UserStore<AdminAppUser>(identityContext);

        var manager = new AdminAppUserManager(userStore);
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<AdminAppUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<AdminAppUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

startup.auth.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AdminAppIdentityDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<AdminAppUserManager>(AdminAppUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //    consumerKey: "",
        //    consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //    appId: "",
        //    appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        //{
        //    ClientId = "",
        //    ClientSecret = ""
        //});
    }
}
```

startup.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

```
public class AdminAppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AdminAppUser>
{
    public AdminAppIdentityDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static AdminAppIdentityDbContext Create()
    {
        return new AdminAppIdentityDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be some sort of ConfigureAuth method that gets called at startup to establish that there is one IdentityDbContext per Owin context.  That call will look like:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(IdentityDbContext.Create);
```

That call should be in the boilerplate that VS generates automatically for you.

Comment: I added my startup class code in my edit.  That call is already there.

Comment: What type does AdminAppIdentityDbContext.Create return?

Comment: it returns `new AdminAppIdentityDbContext();`

Comment: The problem is that the call that is returning null (context.Get<IdentityDbContext>()) is looking for a way to get something of type IdentityDbContext. The app.CreatePerOwnContext call you have is registering a way to return something of type AdminAppIdentityDbContext. If your code needs to call context.Get<IdentityDbContext>(), then your startup code needs to call app.CreatePerOwnContext(IdentityDbContext.Create), or similar. In other words, the types need to match.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just replace 
`var identityContext = context.Get<IdentityDbContext>` with
`var identityContext = new AdminAppIdentityDbContext();`,
it doesn't really matter. It may spare your time.